# Changing Minecraft Biomes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, biomes are (supposedly) decided by an area's calculated temperature and moisture.  A very "dry" area may be a desert, a "cold" area may be a tundra, etc.

This also affects things like grass color.  In my experience, forests tend to have darker grass than plains.

If I, for example, plant a lot of trees in a plain, will it be handled as a forest and make the grass darker?  (There's a specific area of my map that would be great for building a base, but the grass annoys me.)

Comment: Terraforming would be an interesting feature to add.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Biomes are set; you can't change them by adding / removing biome-specific features to areas.